# Detect if image (picture tag) is loaded with JS

Tags: javascript, html, image

So far we are detecting if img is loaded following way in javascript

```
objImg = new Image();
objImg.src = 'photo.gif';

if(objImg.complete) { 
    // Do something
}
```

I wonder do same rules apply when we use `<picture>` tag like this?

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers">
</picture>
```

And if not, how we detect when image is loaded. Thank you

Comment: You simply bind the `load` event listener to the nested `<img>` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen to img tag onload event, even when img is inside `picture` tag

```js
document.querySelector('img').onload = () => console.log('Image loaded');
```

```css
img {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!--Change the browser window width to see the image change.-->
<div>
<picture>
    <source srcset="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553431424-636492c29609?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ"
            media="(min-width: 800px)">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552469489-fc91c433200c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" />
</picture>
</div>
```